# How use function value on table in lua

Tags: function, lua, return, lua-table

I'm new on the moon and I wonder how I can take a function check if the value contained is on a table.

```
local extraItem = {
  Interior = {from = {1602; 2064; 2070; 2108};
          to = {1808; 2065; 2079; 2119};
          id = {2034; 2180; 2192; 2594}}
}

local function onOptionChange(widget, optText, optData)
  if optData >= 16 then
    print(optText)
    for a, v in ipairs(extraItem.optText.from) do
      for i = extraItem.optText.from[a], extraItem.optText.to[a] do
        local widget = g_ui.createWidget('PaletteItem', paletteList)
        local itemid = g_things.getItemType(i)
        widget:setItemId(itemid:getClientId())
      end
    end
    for a, v in ipairs(extraItem.optText.id) do
      local widget = g_ui.createWidget('PaletteItem', paletteList)
      local itemid = g_things.getItemType(v)
      widget:setItemId(itemid:getClientId())
    end
  end
end
```

the `print(optText)` print `Interior` and `extraItem.optText.from` return `nul`, how fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `extraItem[optText]` instead of `extraItem.optText`.

`extraItem.optText` is equivalent to `extraItem["optText"]`.